# Website knows that I'm connected via OpenVPN

Tags: data-leakage, openvpn

When I'm connected to a OpenVPN server and visit `http://ip-api.com/` I get this:

OpenVPN UDP bs128 SHA256

Can somebody explain to me how this is possible and how can I stop this information leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to infer the usage of a VPN from patterns in the communication.

If you are using a tunnelling technology like IPsec, L2TP, or PPTP, your packets are incapsulated inside other packets, so the useful part of the packet might be smaller than in a classic network. MTU and MSS are two important pieces of data about the sizes of the incapsulated packet and the final packet.

**Maximum Transmission Unit** (MTU) is the maximum data that can be transmitted in one packet. Every network has a MTU value, be it a local network or the internet backbone. The most common value is 1500, but there are some exceptions. When using a VPN, your OS sends smaller packets by setting lower MTU values in order to prevent fragmentation in the network that might reduce bandwidth and latency.

When a web browser or any other software that communicates on the network creates TCP connections, it sets **Maximum Segment Size** (MSS) value in the TCP header, which informs the receiver of the maximum TCP data size the transmitter can receive without packet fragmentation. This is very similar to MTU.

**OpenVPN** is a VPN software suite that is more specifically detected because it works in a different way than other VPN software. OpenVPN decreases MSS instead of interface MTU. By decreasing MSS like this, it is possible to further detect the encryption being used because a certain combination of protocol, block size (bs), MAC and compression will generate specific MSS sizes.

**Fix** this information leak in OpenVPN by changing the `mssfix` directive in the OpenVPN config file to different values like 1420, 1360 or 0 (experimental).

Answer (score 1):

How is that possible ? Well: Firefox and Chrome implement WebRTC that allows requests to STUN servers be made that will return the information you see on sites such as `ip-api.com`.

Also the ISPs uses for sure [Deep Packet Inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) (DPI) techniques to inspect traffic so that is why your OpenVPN is detect.

How to avoid such situations ? Many solutions are available, but the one I like the most and which does not need efforts to use (and does not cost anything) is to run [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) on a USB stick so that you protect your  privacy and anonymity.

But if you do not like *easy* solutions then you can  tunnel your OpenVPN via an HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody explain to me how this is possible...

- The IP ranges are registered for the company, so a quick `Whois` can reveal this information. Also a reverse DNS query might reveal the company's URL too.

> ...and how can I stop this information leak?

- You could use a another proxy server or TOR to hide that information